# vim - how to map Ctrl-y to "+y in visual mode?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I can yank a visual selection into the X clipboard in vim using `"+y` - I would like to map this to something more convenient. I tried mapping to Ctrl-y by adding
`:vmap <C-y> \"+y` to my `.vimrc` but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was escaping the `"` character. This, it seems, is wrong in this context. simply:

```
:vmap <C-y> "+y
```

works, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In ~/.vimrc add:

```
vnoremap <C-y> "+y<Esc>
```

or Ctrl-Shift-y:

```
vnoremap <C-S-y> "+y<Esc>
```

Make sure that your terminal does not already use that shortcut. For Gnome terminal see [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en).

Tip: if using default Gnome terminal shortcuts, paste that C-y yanked chars with: C-S-v in terminal or just C-v elsewhere.